# German phrase or idiom for "Stay put!"

Tags: english-to-german, phrase, expression, phrase-request

I'm looking for the German phrase most likely to be used in a tense, dangerous situation (in which a sudden move could get one shot) **to warn people to stay put**.

To be more precise, the warning is coming from one of the good guys, yelling to the other good guys not to move.

My author has "Ort und Stelle bleiben!", but I fear it was arrived at by direct translation, and is unidiomatic.

Comment: For finding a really matching expression you should add a description of the situation where the expression is going to be used.

Comment: It's a work of fiction. It describes a hostage situation, in the moments after the army has intervened and is in the process of identifying and shooting the hostage-takers. One of the hostages is warning the others not to move.

Answer (score 10):

**An Ort und Stelle** has the doubled "place" to assure someone or something is reliably there. That's not what you intend to say.

> Sei an Ort und Stelle!

*Be at that place **reliably**!*

> Bleib an Ort und Stelle!

*Stay at that place **reliably** (I need you to be there)!*

---

Better phrases for your situation just use the verb **bleiben**:

> Bleib, wo du bist!
>
> Bleibt, wo ihr seid!

Telling someone to stay put.

> Bleib weg!

Typical warning from someone at a dangerous place or from someone attempting suicide.

> Bleib stehen!

Telling someone to stop walking or running.

> Stehenbleiben!

Typical movie cop yelling at the bad guy.

---

Sometimes other verbs match better:

> Nicht bewegen!

Typical bomb defusing phrase.

> Halt still!

Typical phrase of someone cutting someone else's shackles.

Comment: I'm very grateful. I shall pass all of this along to my author!

Answer (score 0):

If time is as much an issue as you described I would recommend "Halt!" as a quick shout.